How to remove a part of a custom function when using it in R?
I have a custom function, and it works well.
Gplot = function(mydata, AE){
ggplot(mydata)+
...
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = breaks[2]), color = "seagreen", linetype = "dashed"))
}
...

Sometimes I don't need the vertical line,  so how to remove geom_vline when using it?
I know I can remove this sentence in the function, but I need it most of times. So I just want to  remove it with some specific variables.

That's the wrong approach. The right approach is to add it conditionally and make adding it the default.

@Roland, could you please provide an example link? Thank you!

Using a conditional and only adding the vertical line when the addline argument is TRUE:
Gplot = function(mydata, AE, addline=TRUE){
  gp <- ggplot(mydata)+
  ...
  if(addline){
    gp <- gp + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = breaks[2]))
  }
  return(gp)
}
...

